# ng-image-appear- not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I go through a link below..

[AngularJS Module to make images appear with transition as they load.](https://github.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/ng-image-appear)

[codepen link](http://codepen.io/amdsouza92/pen/aNQeWW)

I use it in my application but not getting tranisition and animation effects

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <img class="img1" src="https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/tropical-beach-background-8.jpg" ng-image-appear responsive transition-duration="1s" animation="fadeInUp" animation-duration="1s" easing="ease-out" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngImageAppear']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.img1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}

.img2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: auto;
}

.img3 {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
}

.loader-class {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
}

.placeholder-class {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the references to your project,

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.image-appear/1.11.3/ng-image-appear.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...I attached it in index file..still no effects

Comment: Hi..problem solved ...Dependency was not added in app.js

Comment: Hi ..sajeetharan ..I don't have right to vote on this answer because I am beginner, Thanks for your answer..